# drag and drop listview in android

Tags: java, android

Im using CursorAdapter in my Listview for direct mapping of data to the database. my problem is when im creating a drag and drop listview. How to drag and drop items in Listview for reordering in android?

Answer (score 2):

There is no default implementation in the Android SDK of a reordering ListView. Here is an implementation that we use in our apps. There are examples of how to use it on the github page.

https://github.com/terlici/DragNDropList